# Find array elements which values are not part of another array PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have two arrays

- `$adg` - (A list of AD groups)
- `$dbs` - (A list of database names)

Lets say I use this command
`$adg -match $dbs.i`

The output will be all the AD groups which have the string `$dbs` in its name.

However, I am aiming to find the DBs in which are not part of the AD groups array.

Eg:

```
$adg = @("Dev22_Owner","Test49_Owner","Rocket_Owner")
$dbs = @("Dev22", "Confidential", "InternDB", "Rocket", "Test49")
```

What approach should I take to get the output:

> `Confidential`
>
> `InternDB`

I tried `$dbs | Where $adg -notmatch $dbs.i` but there is no output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would first remove the unecessary user part from the ad group:

```
$groups = $adg | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace '_.*?$'
}
```

Then you can use the `Where-Object` cmdlet with the `-notin` operator to filter them:

```
$dbs | Where-Object { $_ -notin $groups }
```

**Output:**

```
Confidential
InternDB
```

Answer (score 1):

To offer a more concise PSv3+ alternative to [Martin Brandl's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48862839/45375):

```
PS> (Compare-Object ($adg -replace '_Owner$') $dbs).InputObject
Confidential
InternDB
```

- `($adg -replace '_Owner$')` returns a new array with copies of the input string that have `_Owner` suffix stripped from them.
- [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) compares the stripped array with the other array and returns objects that represent the *differences* between the two arrays.
- Accessing the `.InputObject` on the difference objects returns the values that differ.

  - Note: If `$dbs` contained items that aren't in the stripped `$adg` array, the above would return a *union* of all differing items, irrespective of which side they're unique to; to distinguish the sides / limit to a side, you'd have to use the `.SideIndicator` property (value `=>` indicates values exclusive to the *right* side, `<=` those exclusive to the *left* side).

---

As for **what you tried**:

`$adg -match $dbs.i` doesn't work as intended and is effectively the same as `$adg -match ''`, which invariably returns *all* `$adg` items.

The reason is that array `$dbs` has no `.i` property, so the expression evaluates to `$null`, which on the RHS of match is coerced to a *string* and therefore is converted to the *empty string*.

Generally, **the RHS of `-match` does *not* support arrays** - only a *single* regular expression.

If you do supply an array, it is implicitly converted to a string by joining the elements to form a space-separated list; e.g. array `1, 2` is coerced to `'1 2'` and `'1 2' -match (1, 2)` therefore evaluates to `$True`.